# outer join in mysql not providing the results

Tags: mysql

Hypothetical data -

tbl1  -

| id | date | value1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 200 |
| 101 | 2021-01-03 | 400 |

tbl2  -

| id | date | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 600 |
| 101 | 2021-01-02 | 900 |

My expected result is -

| id | date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2021-01-01 | 200 | 600 |
| 101 | 2021-01-02 | NaN | 900 |
| 101 | 2021-01-03 | 400 | NaN |

```
select * from (select * from tbl1 where id in
(another query)) t1
left join tbl2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date
union all
select * from (select * from tbl1 where id in
(another query)) t1
right join tbl2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date
where t1.id is null and t1.date is null
```

I am unable to figure out where am I going wrong.

Comment: Why not one FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: followed Pablo's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: My bad, heard about mysql don't having a full outer join, but forgot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be overcomplicating your union query:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.value1, t2.value2
FROM tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.id, t2.date, t1.value1, t2.value2
FROM tbl1 t1
RIGHT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.date = t2.date
WHERE t1.id IS NULL
ORDER BY id, date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Collect all present `` (id, `date`) `` pairs then join source data to it:

```sql
SELECT id, `date`, tbl1.value1, tbl2.value2
FROM ( SELECT id, `date` FROM tbl1
       UNION 
       SELECT id, `date` FROM tbl2 ) combined
LEFT JOIN tbl1 USING (id, `date`)
LEFT JOIN tbl2 USING (id, `date`);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73799a16f54d1a67d9520b5279649a0b)

The solution assumes that `` (id, `date`) `` is unique over each separate source table. If not then some aggregation must be used (SUM or MAX, depends on the logic).